# Using fields of a many to many related model as inline in admin forms in django

Tags: python, django-admin

I am facing the problem of adding fields as an inline in admin form. My models are as follows:-

```
class Enrollment(BaseTableCore):
    iclass = models.ForeignKey(InstituteClass,blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL )
    batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch,blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    icourse = models.ForeignKey(InstituteCourse,blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    enroll_num=models.CharField(max_length=20)**

class RegistrationProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='userregistrationprofile')
    activeflag = models.BooleanField(blank=True) # This would be true when the student profile is activated by admin.
    usertype = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_TYPES)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True,blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GENDER_CHOICE,null=True,blank=True)
    mobile_no = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,help_text="Please Enter Your Mobile No : ")
    enrollment = models.ManyToManyField(Enrollment, through='ProfileEnrollment')
    courses_applied = models.ManyToManyField(InstituteCourse,through='AppliedForCourse')

class ProfileEnrollment(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(RegistrationProfile)
    enrollment = models.ForeignKey(Enrollment)

class AppliedForCourse(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(RegistrationProfile)
    courses = models.ForeignKey(InstituteCourse)
    batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch)
```

My admin form where I'm having a problem is as follows:-

```
class AppliedForCourseInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = AppliedForCourse
    fieldsets = ((None,{
        'fields':('courses','batch')}),
    )
    extra =0

class ProfileEnrollementInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProfileEnrollment
    extra = 0

class RegistrationProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = RegistrationProfileAdminForm
    inlines = [AppliedForCourseInline,ProfileEnrollementInline]
    fieldsets = ((None,{
        'fields':('user','activeflag','usertype')}),
    )
```

The inline for `AppliedForCourse` is working as usual but trouble comes with the requirements for `ProfileEnrollmentInline` as I need to display `icourse`, `iclass`, `batch` & `enroll_num` fields of `Enrollment` model in the inline.

I can't seem to figure out the solution, how to proceed for this problem?